# "You've got to be strong" and "You should be strong" are the same?

Tags: difference, modal-verbs, synonyms

Are there some differences in sentences

> *You've got to be strong*.

and

> *You should be strong.*

Are they the same?

Comment: I will add that to add to the confusion here, "You've got to be strong" is something of an idiomatic phrase used to encourage or comfort someone to whom some kind of tragedy has happened. You should be strong would have the opposite of this connotation.

Comment: Who taught you to use *Got* in this way? They should be flogged and impaled. _You have to be strong and resist the urge to misuse 'got'._

Comment: @JoeDark - Who taught him? You've got to be kidding. "You've got to be strong" is a common expression, often used in the way Vality mentioned. Do you really think people have got to be impaled for using words in a way you don't approve of?

Comment: @nnnnnn You, ofcourse, meant to say, 'You have to be kidding.' Are you saying that because an expression is common it automatically becomes correct English? You is trippin'.

Comment: @JoeDark - Ah, but what is "correct English"?

Comment: @JoeDark - I said what I meant. Though of course I overused "have got to" in order to make my point. "You've got to be kidding" is an *extremely* common idiom that has been around for decades, so there seems little point in trying to object to it now. I would classify "You've got to" as informal English, typically spoken more than written, but not actually incorrect. (Don't *you* mean to say "you be trippin'"?

Comment: @nnnnnn Well, this has _'gotten'_ tedious _extremely_ quickly. We need to get _'off of'_ this topic before you start calling it ironic.  If, however, you can provide any actual proof that the use of; _'You've got to be...'_ is the correct and/or standardized use of *got*, then I'll be only too happy to remove my comments. You might also want to look up the definition of idiom. You have a nice day now y'hear.

Comment: @J.R. I doubt anyone in their right mind would claim that any version of the English language is immutable. Somethings however, are simply more correct than others.  Using the past tense/participle of _get_ in this way is simply incorrect regardless _(not irregardless)_ of how common a phrase it may be.

Comment: @JoeDark - So what, disagreement about usage of "got" means I must be ignorant about what "ironic" means? If I used "idiom" incorrectly I must be wrong about everything? I meant that "You've got to" is an idiomatic usage of "got". I already said that it is an informal usage. I don't claim that it's the primary usage. The dictionary indicates that this usage is less common in American English than in British English; I speak Australian English (which is of course closer to British than American).

Comment: @Joe - _incorrect_ is a strong word. [This dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/got) prefers the softer term _informal_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are things we *need* to do, and there are things we *should* do. Think of "needs" as requirements, while "shoulds" are recommendations.

So, if you want to convey that it is absolutely essential to remain strong, use one of these:

> We need to be strong.
>   We must be strong.
>   We've got to be strong.

On the other hand, if you are recommending that we remain strong, use one of these:

> We should be strong.
>   We ought to be strong.

And if you want to express confidence that our strength will not falter:

> We will remain strong.
>   We shall remain strong.

Comment: Slightly disagreeing with your last paragraph.  In my dialect, "we will remain strong" expresses confidence or determination that our strength will not falter, whereas  "we shall remain strong" is an emotionally neutral future tense.

Answer (score 0):

Their meanings are the same, but their use contexts are slightly different. 
While both mean roughly the same thing ('you need to become stronger'), 'you've got to' is more impassioned and more personal (and slightly more informal) than 'you should'.

Comment: Your answer makes me wonder if the "slightly more informal" difference would disappear if the first one was expanded to _"You have got to be strong."_

Answer (score 0):

They're not the same.

> You've got to be strong.

This means that you *need* to be strong, that is that strength is a mandatory requirement for the situation.

This expression is often used in reference to emotional strength needed to weather a current or expected crisis, though of course it can refer to physical strength.

> You should be strong.

This could be interpreted in more than one way depending on the context. It could mean that strength is desirable but perhaps not necessary if you have other qualities that apply. For example you could win a fight using brute strength or by using superior speed to knock out your opponent before they have a chance to use their superior strength. In my experience this expression is much less likely to be applied to emotional strength: you might say "You've got to be strong to cope with a divorce", but you wouldn't say "You should be strong to cope with a divorce."